# How to load huge data in firebase recyclerview efficiently

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

There is something more than 6000 entries in child mDatabase

```
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("CurrentQuizResult");

    Query query = mDatabase.orderByChild("score");

    final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<BlogScore, AffairsHigh.BlogScoreViewHolder> FirebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
            <BlogScore, AffairsHigh.BlogScoreViewHolder>(BlogScore.class, R.layout.blogscore, AffairsHigh.BlogScoreViewHolder.class, query) {


        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final AffairsHigh.BlogScoreViewHolder viewHolder, BlogScore model, final int position) {




            final String post_key = getRef(position).getKey();

            
            });
            viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
            viewHolder.setUserimage(getApplicationContext(), model.getUserimage());
            viewHolder.setUsername(model.getUsername(),post_key,getApplicationContext());
        }


    };


    mBlogList.setAdapter(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

But in this code, it is downloading all 6000 nodes in mDatabase child which are consuming high database usage. Here how I can load data whose score is greater than 200 so that in Query it doesn't load useless data which not required. Any solution for that using Query in firebase??

Answer (score 0):

To only load the data where the score is larger than 200, you can do:

```
Query query = mDatabase.orderByChild("score").startAt(200);
```

For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data).

---

If the app is still downloading all data, even when you add a filter, you may not have added a server-side index in your database's security rules.

For the query you run, you need to have this index in your rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "CurrentQuizResult": {
      ".indexOn": "score"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's again downloading all data in mDatabase child but by your code, it's showing only those items whose score is greater than 200. But the things it's consuming high data usage which is costing me very much. I tried with a score of more than 600 which not even exists but again downloading all data. I want it to be efficient so that it not consumes useless data usage.

Comment: Check the logcat output for any message related to a missing index. If there is such a message, you're missing an index and need to add it as described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data. I also added an example to my answer.

Comment: I tried with the rules which you suggested above but still downloading data.

Comment: Did you check the logcat output for the message I suggested?

Comment: Hey @Manik Any update here? Did you check the logcat output?